# Adding JSpeex Jar file to Blackberry Project

Tags: blackberry, java-me, speex

I am trying to add JSpeex's jar file to Blackberry project.
Compilation fails if I add it.

Also, if I add source files to the project, compilation fails as JSpeex is pure Java and classes are not supported in Blackberry app.

Please help me to resolve the issue...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Pure Java? Keep in mind that the Blackberry JVM is still based on [J2ME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Micro_Edition), which is kind of a subset of java.

To include external JAR follow the Knowledge Base Entry

[How To - Compile a jar file into a BlackBerry Library](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800901/How_To_-_Compile_a_JAR_file_into_a_BlackBerry_Library.html?nodeid=801017&vernum=0)

Another way is to extract your jar file (change the file ending to .zip instead of .jar and extract the source files) and using the preverify option to check your java classes.

```
preverify.exe [-d] output -classpath directory input; directory
```

Good Luck,
rAyt

**Edit in response to your comment**

In   `C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 4.7\bin` try

```
preverify -classpath "C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 4.7\lib\net_rim_api.jar" "d:\myjar.jar"
```

and look in the output folder.

Comment: Thanks rAyt, I reffered to the link you gave and tried to build the library project first.
Im getting :  JSpeexDec: Error!: Missing stack map at label: 39
Error while building project
while building library project containing speex jar.
How do I solve this error?

Comment: This is very old, but I am drudging it up again due to the fact that RedPhone uses `Speex` and I am interested in attempting a port to `QNX 10.2`.  Did you work this out?