# Blackberry: How do I import a contact list from my google account to a blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry, google-api

What are the steps to use a google account to store my contact list, using it as a database and linking it to eclipse, when creating a Blackberry app?

I am new to blackberry development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access Google data you need the Google Data Library:

> http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/

The developer's guide and getting started page

> http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_java.html

Answer (score 0):

Please use this http://www.google.com/mobile/sync/ .  It will show you how to do it.

Comment: Sorry, my project is actually using google contacts as a database, and now i'm currently trying to create an application using eclipse which requires us to retrieve the data from the google apps, displaying it in the eclipse BB Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example:

> http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/contacts/ContactsExample.java

And don't forget to preverify the gdata library before including it into the BB project

 How to preverify:
[Adding JSpeex Jar file to Blackberry Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287011/adding-jspeex-jar-file-to-blackberry-project/1287111#1287111)